# Associate files with specific extension to my own application in Python

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I have created an app. It uses some database file to show its contents in a wxpython frame.
Let us assume the database file extension is .xyz. When I double-click on an .xyz file, I want to open that file in my application and call a function inside my app to process it. How can I do it in Python and in Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would figure win32 would have a play in this, maybe there is an environmental variable for it too...

Comment: Registry setting.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625297/c-proper-way-for-file-associations

Comment: Is there any solution for modifying file association so it could be cross platform (windows, linux, os-x) in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ftype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx) and [assoc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx) will enable you to do that (reasonable) version independent way.

In your python script you may like to use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) to parse your command line arguments (which you specified to `ftype`).

Comment: I do not only want to associate the file with my app but also to evaluate it inside a local function. I mean I need a way to pass the file to my app.

Comment: @Shansal: wouldn't `ftype` allow you just do that? Or do you mean that your application is all ready running? Thanks

Comment: If I want to pass the file path to the app, then what should I do?

Comment: @Shansal: %1 is the file (and its path) in ftype specification. You may like to show to us your actual ftype spec. Thanks

Comment: Could you give some code to parse the open command string for an arbitrary file extension by using argparse. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not related to Python itself, but it is Windows configuration. You have to assign file type to the application. I guess the method how you do that depends on Windows version. Here is example for Vista: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default

Comment: I do not only want to associate the file with my app but also to evaluate it inside a local function. I mean I need a way to pass the file to my app.

Comment: That's what file assoc will do for you. Your application will be opened with the file as argument and you can process it then